# How to increase the size of HTML application window?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Writing to ask **how I would go about increasing the size on the inside HTML application window using script.**

I am currently creating a Google Sheet worksheet and I also have created a script within Google Apps Script to make it so a user can print the worksheet through Google Cloud Print. However, **when I click to print, the actual Cloud Print application window is tiny compared to the outside box** (See picture below for better representation of what I mean.)

[image]

So the box itself is 300 x 500 but the inside window is half the width of that, therefore cutting off most of the window. I just wanted to know if there's any way of making the inside window bigger or to match the size of the outside application box? Below is the entire code I use.

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Click to print')
      .addItem('Print from Google Cloud', 'openDialog')
      .addToUi();
}

function openDialog() {

  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
    .setWidth(300)
    .setHeight(500)
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Click the button below, select a printer then adjust your settings and then click Print.');


}
```

and the ***index.html*** code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://www.google.com/cloudprint/client/cpgadget.js">
</script>
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var gadget = new cloudprint.Gadget();
    gadget.setPrintButton(
    cloudprint.Gadget.createDefaultPrintButton("button"));
    var liabilityWaiver = waiver.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
    gadget.setPrintDocument("url", "Test Page", "https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3NraNAa2RhWSldiNklPVGI5OU0");
  }
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="button"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are seeing is the box that displays is too large- take a look if you adjust the box size to the below, it fits much better.

```js
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Click to print')
      .addItem('Print from Google Cloud', 'openDialog')
      .addToUi();
}

function openDialog() {

  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
    .setWidth(670)
    .setHeight(500)
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Click the button below, select a printer then adjust your settings and then click Print.');


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
<script src="https://www.google.com/cloudprint/client/cpgadget.js">
</script>
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var gadget = new cloudprint.Gadget();
    gadget.setPrintButton(
        cloudprint.Gadget.createDefaultPrintButton("print_button_container")); // div id to contain the button
    gadget.setPrintDocument("url", "Test Page", "https://www.google.com/landing/cloudprint/testpage.pdf");
    gadget.openPrintDialog();
  }
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="button"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

indox to print a google spreadsheet

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
<script src="https://www.google.com/cloudprint/client/cpgadget.js">
</script>
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var gadget = new cloudprint.Gadget();
    gadget.setPrintButton(
        cloudprint.Gadget.createDefaultPrintButton("print_button_container")); // div id to contain the button
    gadget.setPrintDocument("google.spreadsheet", "Test Page", "SPREADSHEET-ID-GOES-HERE");
    gadget.openPrintDialog();
  }
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="button"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh yes, I see. Thanks so much for this, so simple but I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Will probably need to ask another question but i'll ask here just to save me spamming questions. Now that I can see all of the window, when I hit the print button nothing happens? Is that to do with the coding? (Probably, since i'm not well versed in Google Apps Script or HTML really.)

Comment: try using the index.html I added. Now no button at all- straight to printer select window

Comment: Sorry I should've been more specific, the button created to GET to the printer selection window works fine. It's the actual final "Print" button AFTER selecting a printer that doesn't work and was wondering if it was down to the code or something not related? Again, sorry for not being more specific.

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure why that is happening- but if you try my example it does work- and print. Plus less steps :-)

Comment: Brilliant, really appreciate it. Gotta pick your brain again. If I wanted to print the active worksheet in Google Sheets and not from a URL, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Really appreciate all the help you've been, all sorted now! Consider yourself my best friend when it comes to Google Sheets!